# How to output my results all the way at the end of my program versus at the end of each iteration? (Updated version of previous query)

Tags: c, function, output, marquee

So my program takes a string, and then outputs it as a marquee sign. I have a for loop so that it may take multiple strings and then outputs each of the strings as a sign.

My problem is: after each iteration, it outputs the sign, and then continues to prompt me for the next string when I want it to just take in all my inputs at once, and then output every sign at the very end. Here is what I'm talking about:

```
Current Input:
3
Hello World!
5
Sign #1: (This is the output)
[Hello]
[ello ]
[llo W]
[lo Wo]
[o Wor]
[ Worl]
[World]
[orld!]
[rld! ]
[ld! H]
[d! He]
[! Hel]
[ Hell]
Activist
10
Sign #2: (This is the output)
[Activist  ]
LOL
2
Sign #3: (This is the output)
[LO]
[OL]
[L ]
[ L]
```

This is what I want it to do:

```
Input:
3
Hello World!
5
Activist
10
LOL
2 
Output:
Sign #1: 
[Hello]
[ello ]
[llo W]
[lo Wo]
[o Wor]
[ Worl]
[World]
[orld!]
[rld! ]
[ld! H]
[d! He]
[! Hel]
[ Hell]

Sign #2:
[Activist  ]

Sign #3:
[LO]
[OL]
[L ]
[ L]
```

Here is my ORIGINAL code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void ignoreRestOfLine(FILE *fp) {
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n');
}

int main() {
    int num_times, count = 0;
    int marq_length, sign = 0;
    scanf("%d ", &num_times);
    char s[100];

    for (count = 0; count < num_times; count++) {
        if (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) == NULL) {
            // Deal with error.
        }
        if (scanf("%d", &marq_length) != 1) {
            // Deal with error.
        }
        ignoreRestOfLine(stdin);

        size_t n = strlen(s) - 1;
        int i, j;

        if (s[strlen(s)-1] == '\n')
            s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';

        printf("Sign #%d:\n", ++sign);

        if (n <= marq_length) {
            printf("[%-*s]\n", marq_length, s);
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
                putchar('[');
                for (j = 0; j < marq_length; j++) {
                    char c = s[(i + j) % (n + 1)];
                    if (!c)
                        c = ' ';
                    putchar(c);
                }
                printf("]\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my UPDATED code, where I added the part of my code that actually outputs the string in a marquee sign into a function. I just don't know how to properly call it back to the main function so it can output all the signs at the very end:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void ignoreRestOfLine(FILE* fp){
   int c;
   while ( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n');
}

char getSign(char s[100], int marq_length);
char getSign(char s[100], int marq_length){

    int count =0;
    int sign =0;
    //char s[100];
    if ( fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) == NULL )
    {
       // Deal with error.
    }

    if ( scanf("%d", &marq_length) != 1 )
    {
       // Deal with error.
    }

    ignoreRestOfLine(stdin);

    size_t n = strlen(s)-1;
    int i,j;


        if(s[strlen(s)-1] == '\n')
            s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';

            printf("Sign #%d:\n", ++sign);

    if (n <= marq_length) {
        printf("[%-*s]\n", marq_length, s);
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
            putchar('[');
            for (j = 0; j < marq_length; j++) {
                char c = s[(i + j) % (n + 1)];
                if (!c)
                    c = ' ';
                putchar(c);
            }
            printf("]\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int i, num_times, sign_length;
    char string[100];
    scanf("%d", &num_times);
    //char *results=malloc(num_times * sizeof(char));
    for(i=0 ;i<num_times;i++){
        scanf("%s", string);
        scanf("%d", &sign_length);
        printf((getSign(string, sign_length)));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie please review this and tell me what you think

Comment: Passing the result as the first argument of `printf()` is very bad idea. What if the input is `%s%s%s%s%s`? You should use `printf("%s", getSign())` or `fputs(getSign(), stdout)` instead. (arguments of `getSign()` are omitted) ... if `getSign()` returns valid pointer to string.

Comment: Can't you just collect the input strings in a 2D array? Just make one for-loop for the input and another for printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is good to read all input and then print results because input is short and these size are easy to predict.

Your `main()` function should be like this

```
int main(void){
    int i, num_times, *sign_length;
    char (*string)[100];
    /* read number of test cases */
    scanf("%d", &num_times);
    /* allocate buffer to store input */
    sign_length = malloc(sizeof(*sign_length) * num_times);
    string = malloc(sizeof(*string) * num_times);
    if (sign_length == NULL || string == NULL) {
        free(sign_length);
        free(string);
        return 1;
    }
    /* read input */
    for(i=0 ;i<num_times;i++){
        scanf("%99s", string[i]);
        scanf("%d", &sign_length[i]);
    }
    /* process and print */
    for(i=0 ;i<num_times;i++){
        getSign(string[i], sign_length[i]);
    }
    /* cleanup */
    free(string);
    free(sign_length);
    return 0;
}
```

and the part that are trying to destroy the input in `getSign()`

```
    if ( fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) == NULL )
    {
       // Deal with error.
    }

    if ( scanf("%d", &marq_length) != 1 )
    {
       // Deal with error.
    }

    ignoreRestOfLine(stdin);
```

have to be deleted.

`#include <stdlib.h>` have to be added to the head of your code to use `malloc()` and `free()`.

**UPDATE:** Here is a program with problems fixed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void getSign(char s[100], int marq_length, int case_number);
void getSign(char s[100], int marq_length, int case_number){

    size_t n = strlen(s)-1;
    size_t i,j;
    if (strlen(s) < n) n = 0;

    if(s[n] == '\n')
        s[n] = '\0';
    else
        n++;

    printf("Sign #%d:\n", case_number);

    if (n <= (size_t)marq_length) {
        printf("[%-*s]\n", marq_length, s);
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
            putchar('[');
            for (j = 0; j < (size_t)marq_length; j++) {
                char c = s[(i + j) % (n + 1)];
                if (!c)
                    c = ' ';
                putchar(c);
            }
            printf("]\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(void){
    int i, num_times, *sign_length;
    char (*string)[100];
    /* read number of test cases */
    if(scanf("%d", &num_times) != 1) return 1;
    /* allocate buffer to store input */
    sign_length = malloc(sizeof(*sign_length) * num_times);
    string = malloc(sizeof(*string) * num_times);
    if (sign_length == NULL || string == NULL) {
        free(sign_length);
        free(string);
        return 1;
    }
    /* read input */
    for(i=0 ;i<num_times;i++){
        int dummy;
        while((dummy = getchar()) != '\n' && dummy != EOF); /* skip rest of previous line */
        if(scanf("%99[^\n]%d", string[i], &sign_length[i]) != 2) {
            free(sign_length);
            free(string);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    /* process and print */
    for(i=0 ;i<num_times;i++){
        getSign(string[i], sign_length[i], i + 1);
    }
    /* cleanup */
    free(string);
    free(sign_length);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My program just crashes

Answer (score 0):

The approach I'd take here is to either store the input until all input is read and only then to generate the output, or to store the output and defer it's printing until the end.

The first is IMHO opinion the better approach, because the amount of data to store is less. OTOH is storing the output a good first step to parallelize taking input and generating output. I go with the later as this is closer to the wording in your question.

OK, your output is basically a C string. So you need to store one of these for each input that you get. Luckily you know even before the first iteration how many inputs you'll get, so you can just allocate the correct amount of space beforehand:

```
char const ** outputs; // A pointer to (an array of) constant C strings
outputs = malloc(sizeof(*outputs) * numInputs);
```

Then, you read input as you do it and generate your output into a C string. You've been using a stack allocated (constant size) buffer for that. To be able to reuse that buffer in each iteration you need to copy your result out of it:

```
char * result = malloc(strlen(sign) + 1);
strcpy(result, sign);
```

And the store that into your array of outputs:

```
outputs[currentIteration] = result;
```

Finally, at the end you print each output and free the allocated memory when done with it:

```
for (size_t o = 0; o < numOutputs; ++o) {
  printf("%s\n", outputs[o]);
  free(outputs[o]);
}
```

At the end, don't forget to also free the array that has been allocated for the outputs:

```
free(outputs);
```

Notes: You should check each and every allocation whether it succeeded. Moreover, using a constant sized buffer (on the stack) is OK *only if* you make absolutely sure that this buffer will never overflow! You should try to pack as much of the above and your sign generation in (small) functions.

---

Sketch of the overall code:

```
int main() {
  // read how many inputs you'll get
  // allocate outputs
  // iterate, so that for each input:
    // you read the input
    // generate the sign
    // copy the result into the outputs array
  // iterate over all outputs
    // print output
    // free allocated memory of that output
  // free memory for outputs
}
```

Reading the input and generating the sign should be done in two distinct functions (so its neither the original nor the updated code). Basically I think having these functions should give you a reasonable code structure:

```
// Read both the string and length, allocating memory for the string
bool read_input(char **string, unsigned * marq_length);
// Could alternatively be done with a fixed buffer
bool read_input(char * string, size_t max_string_size, unsigned * marq_length);

// Note: for bool include stdbool, or use a char instead
```

And one to generate the sign:

```
// Store the result in the fixed size buffer at dest, check for overflow!
void generate_sign(char * dest, size_t max_dest_size, char const * input, unsigned marq_length);
```

Things like printing the outputs could be done directly in main, or in a dedicated function.